# how to arguments to function in AWS Glue Map.Apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I would like to pass arguments to the function used in map.apply

````
def awsome_function(needed_input_var):
....


Map.apply(frame=products_combination, f=awsome_function(??????))
```

I don't see a way to do this.
````

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended. Map should only take a `DynamicFrame` as input.

[Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map-apply) says:

> Builds a new DynamicFrame by applying a function to all records in the
> input DynamicFrame.

Comment: I read that but its pretty hard to tell if that's the case from that sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Lambda function to pass additional arguments to your awesome function.

For example:

```
def awsome_function(product: dict, arg: int) -> dict:
    product['awesome'] = product['some_int'] + arg
    return product

def main():
    ...
    some_arg: int = 10
    Map.apply(
        frame=products_combination, 
        f=lambda product: awsome_function(product=product, arg=some_arg),
    )
```